# Is there a 'break on mutate' equivalent in Firebug 3?

Tags: firefox, firebug

Is there something like the [*Break On Mutate* button](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Break_On_Mutate) from the old Firebug versions in Firebug 3?

How to break on HTML changes, for example to debug hover state changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet in the alpha versions of Firebug 3.

Though there is a [bug 1005825](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005825) filed to add this feature to the built-in DevTools. And because Firebug 3 is based on the DevTools, it will have that feature, too, once it is implemented into the DevTools.